# Logstash fails to send emails when i use a variable as an email trigger keyword

Tags: email, output, logstash, keyword

I have configured logstash in a way we can dynamically configure the alert keyword which will send an email when it appears in message. 
Logstash fails to send emails when i use a variable as an email trigger keyword.

My old configuration worked: I got emails when there is ERROR keyword in message

```
 if "ERROR" in [message] {
email {
  address=>"mailsrv.unix.gsm1900.org"
  port=>25
  from => "logstash_alert@t-mobile.com"
  subject => "(${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}) Logstash Alert from ${APPLICATION_NAME}"
  via => "smtp"
  to => "${CLIENT_MAIL}"
  body => "In host ${HOST_IP:HOST_NOT_SET} the event line that occurred: %{message}"
}
```

New config: It is not sending any emails. I have setup the ERROR key word for this variable in /etc/default/logstash file

```
 if "${EXCEPTION_STRING}" in [message] {
email {
  address=>"mailsrv.unix.gsm1900.org"
  port=>25
  from => "logstash_alert@t-mobile.com"
  subject => "(${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}) Logstash Alert from ${APPLICATION_NAME}"
  via => "smtp"
  to => "${CLIENT_MAIL}"
  body => "In host ${HOST_IP:HOST_NOT_SET} the event line that occurred: %{message}"
}
```

Please help here. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Jump in your wayback machine to [2016](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/5115) to see that variables are not supported in conditionals.  That post provides a workaround of setting the variable into metadata, which can then be used in the conditional:

```
mutate {
  add_field => { "[@metadata][EXCEPTION_STRING]" => "${EXCEPTION_STRING}" }
}

if [@metadata][EXCEPTION_STRING] in [message] {
  ...
}
```